# Is this the most efficient way to track word changes in a string?

Tags: algorithm, ruby, strings, parsing, edit-distance

I'm working on a writing platform and am using a modified version of [the Levenshtein distance algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to track a writer's engagement with their writing. It tracks not only words added to their content, but also rewards editing by including words removed and words substituted in the count.

Here's my algorithm in Ruby (which I run between (auto)saves):

```
def words_changed_since(second)
  first = self.split # array of words in first string
  second = second.split # array of words in second string

  # initialize the matrix
  matrix = [(0..first.length).to_a]
  (1..second.length).each do |j|
    matrix << [j] + [0] * (first.length)
  end

  # for each word in the second string
  (1..second.length).each do |i|
    # for each word in the first string
    (1..first.length).each do |j|
      if first[j-1] == second[i-1]
        matrix[i][j] = matrix[i-1][j-1]
      else
        matrix[i][j] = [
          matrix[i-1][j], # word deletion
          matrix[i][j-1], # word insertion
          matrix[i-1][j-1] # word substitution
        ].min + 1
      end
    end
  end
  return matrix.last.last
end
```

**Is this the most efficient way of tracking these changes?**

Comment: Kindly provide some explanation of what you are doing here. For example, I assume from the Wiki you reference that you are using a dynamic programming approach and `matrix[i,j]` equals the Levenshtein distance between the first i characters of `first` the first j characters of `second`.  It would help the reader a lot to just know that.  Also, it should be noted that the `else` calculation of `matrix[i,j]` corresponds to a deletion, insertion and substitution, respectively.  You should not have to be asked for such basic and essential information.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I added some comments to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: why not use `diff-lcs` algorithm instead ? see [Diff::LCS](http://rubydoc.info/github/halostatue/diff-lcs)

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, diff-lcs would show me the number of changes made and the changes themselves. I want to track words, specifically, not just substrings, so Levenshteins algorithm seemed more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby is fundamentally more about simplicity (readability) than about time/memory efficiency. Otherwise you should choose another language. There are such high level languages, that can beat Ruby, like for example Javascript. And even Python handle strings faster than Ruby at the cost of eternal problems with encodings (don't waste your time on crutches, choose tools wisely).
And even inside Ruby single replacements of one method chain with another can either be efficient or not, depending on your platform (jruby? rubinius? etc.) while there are still different ways to measure an algorithmic complexity especially for your unique kind of input data.

So anyway.

1. The `matrix` creation I would write in one of these two ways:

   ```
   matrix = (0..second.size).map{ |i|
     (0..first.size).map{ |j|
       i==0 ? j : j == 0 ? i : 0
     }
   }

   matrix = (0..second.size).map{ |i|
     i==0 ? (0..first.size).to_a : [i]+[0]*first.size
   }
   ```

   There is also a solution via `transpose`, but not functional, and one via `zip` in which I doubt.
2. You can omit the `return` keyword at the last line in Ruby functions.

And this is not Ruby-related, but in the main loop try to iterate through `0...second.length` instead of `1..second.length` (same for `first`). In that way you'll swap `i-1` with `i` and `i` with `i+1`, getting rid of two decrements in total.

Comment: Is the alternative code in (1) actually more efficient, or just fewer characters? Efficiency is the only thing I'm really worried about. As for (2), I know there's that option in Ruby, but for methods that are more than one line, I personally like to include the return, just to be explicit.

Comment: As for your first comments, I'm using ruby 2.0.0p247 and am running this on rails, so ruby or javascript are probably my best options. I suppose I could handle this operation client-side with js, so I'll keep that in mind if this turns out to be a bottleneck in production.

Comment: @ChrisFritz, I didn't benchmark, but your way looks faster. But it is more iterative, than functional -- it is just not Ruby style.